# Inappropriate meaning of "inappropriate", depending on context

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, context

The meaning of the word "inappropriate" somewhat changes depending on context.

In the sentence

> In an email reply to my professor, I misunderstood what he told me and
>   wrote something **inappropriate**.

the word means something that is at least a little insulting, hurting or irritating in a negative sense.

When I say the use of "inappropriate" in the text is inappropriate, that does just mean the word is not used in the right manner, with no further implications.

The correct meaning (assuming no rudeness, insult etc) with only one word changed would be

> In an email reply to my professor, I misunderstood what he told me and
>   wrote something **wrong**.

It can be written in nicer forms, but this is a modified example from a real question text.

I think the best example of this effect, is the word, "fuck".
It can even have context dependence on the voice modulation!

I am sure there are many examples - write as comments if you like!

So, are my assumptions right?
Does this context dependent meaning change have a name?
Is there some more formal description of it?

Comment: "Inappropriate", in the sense of "offensive" or "insulting" is something of a euphemism.  As such it's meaning must be (mis)interpreted via context and tone.

Answer (score 1):

[**Inappropriate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inappropriate) actually means *not suitable*—but it doesn't define *why* it's unsuitable.

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : not appropriate : UNSUITABLE • *inappropriate* behavior • The movie's subject matter is *inappropriate* for small children.

Something can be unsuitable because it's insulting  just as much as it can be unsuitable because it's used incorrectly.

In some contexts, an insulting word can actually be appropriate and correct. (If you're trying to write crude jokes, language that is *not* insulting could be considered inappropriate.)

---

Meaning often *is* dependent on context. But I am unaware of any single word that describes this.

The National Center for Biotechnology Information website has a PubMed Central article called ["Context-Dependent Interpretation Of Words: Evidence For Interactive Neural Processes"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2577612/). It starts by saying the following:

> The meaning of a word usually depends on the context in which it occurs. This study investigated the neural mechanisms involved in computing word meanings that change as a function of syntactic context.

Note that the article uses *context-dependent interpretation of words* rather than anything shorter. With respect to your question, I would say that you'd have to live with something similar, such as **context-dependent meaning**.

---

There is the word [**homonym**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homonym), but I believe it's too specific for your question:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1 a** *grammar* : HOMOPHONE • the *homonyms there* and *their*
> **b** *grammar* : HOMOGRAPH • The words *lead*, as in the metal, and *lead*, as in the verb, are *homonyms*.
> **c** *grammar* : one of two or more words spelled and pronounced alike but different in meaning (such as the noun *quail* and the verb *quail*)

Comment: "Inappropriate actually means not suitable—but it doesn't define why it's unsuitable": well said, and it explains why I sometimes see people using the word "inappropriate" in a dismissive way—they can reject what someone is saying without explaining why and while blaming the person for saying the wrong thing.